# SQL Server login timeout expired when running sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlcmd

Today I have some strange error on SQL Server. Something like this:

[image]

I don't know what I should do. This is happening when I want to run query more than 200MB. But I guess, the size doesn't matter. Can anyone guide me to fix this problem?

And, for some reason, I can't export SQL Server data for more than 100MB, so can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is your SQL file larger than 200MB?

Comment: Is it a new error or has it never worked? I don't know whats strange about it - "SQL Server is not found" is a straightforward error with many ways to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

Your error messages say a couple of different things:

> Login timeout expired
>
> ... Server is not found or accessible ...
>
> Could not open connection to SQL Server

If you look over the command parameters for `sqlcmd` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility).

You're passing in `s` which is  `col_separator`, rather than server which is `S` (note the capitalization).

Next you're probably going to need an authorization strategy, whether that is `E` for Integrated Security, or using `U` and `P` for userid and password respectively.

Try those and see what you're getting.

You could, of course, always try using SSMS rather than sqlcmd.

Edit: Looks like integrated security is by default, so you don't need to specify `E` unless you just want to.

Comment: This is the first Windows utility I've had to use where the case on the switch mattered (or I've just been lucky until now).